# How to convert a Python List to a PHP array via a MySQL table

Tags: php, python, mysql, arrays, list

I have inherited a MySQL database where one of the fields in a table returns a string that was once a Python list so I get something like this:

```
$test = "[u'Person 1', u'Person 2']";
```

What is the cleanest/easiest/best/simplest (I'm not sure how to phrase this) to get this data back into an array in PHP?  I am using PHP4 but I could upgrade to PHP5.4 if necessary.

I don't have much experience programming in PHP and my first thought was to do something like this:

```
$new = explode(",",$test);
```

This kind of works but it would need cleaning up afterwards (for instance each element of the array has at least u' in front of it) and is obviously fragile if any of the elements contain a comma.

Is there a cleaner/easier/better/simpler way of doing this?

Comment: Definitely look at upgrading to PHP 5.  Version 4 is obsolete.

Comment: PHP4 is ancient and should never be used for new applications.

Comment: if I were you, I'd convert all the fields to something less language dependent like JSON (You can do that from python). Then you can access 'em with whatever language you need

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to alter the python scripts, I'm stuck with using PHP to transform the data.  I hear everyone about PHP4 being obsolete but I am trying to do this for a friend who is using PHP4 (it would be easier if I didn't have to persuade them to upgrade, I've tried and failed before).

Comment: Why are you using 2 languages instead of just continuing to use Python? Do you have a Python backend and a PHP front end?

Comment: Jordan, you are correct Python backend with a PHP frontend.  To make matters worse both are programmed by different people too!

Comment: PHP4, poorly coded python software you can't modify, data serialized as language-specific structures, doing free work for a "friend" - this is going to get a lot uglier before it gets better.

Comment: This app is poorly designed from the get-go from what you said.  Looks like you need to restart building it from square one.  Storing arrays on the database is silly to begin with, why not just normalize the data?  If that wasn't reasonable, why did the coder do it in a proprietary format, why not use JSON?  This is all wrong.

Comment: Geez, I never thought this would be such an issue.  I have got the situation I have got and I have to deal with this situation.  I am not saying it is great and I hear everyone who says it is poorly designed.  What I am looking for is a solution not a debate on how bad the current design is!

Comment: The solution is for you to help them fix their scripts and existing datastore.  It's not many lines of code.  The problem is that while you're looking for an easy fix on addressing the frontend concerns, that doesn't exist.  There is no easy fix.  You're assuming that the data is all one type, but they may have a mixture of different data structures in there, added over time.

Comment: No Jonathan this isn't the solution.  I never said there was an easy fix.  The data is all one type, what gave you the impression it wasn't?  You and everyone else are reading way too much into this.

Comment: Many of us have inherited issues like this before - legacy data is messy. Your strings were not written according to a given specification , and you did not state that "Each and every entry in the database is formatted exactly like this".  If you were to assume that everything were a flat list, a valid list could contain anything along the lines of `[1,'1',u'1']`, and then you have all sorts of data types and objects.  Even if everything were a string, depending on the Python version or options, some elements could be a 'bystring' or a u'unicodestring'.

Comment: It's also incredibly not standard or recommended to toss a Python list into a database field like that.  When people do things like that, it's a huge warning sign that you're going to run into issues - and you should be proactive in how you approach things: either fixing the underlying problems (how data is stored) or auditing the database to ensure each and every current record matches the spec and that future records are written to it.  Everyone is trying to offer you solutions to your actual problem, but you're insisting on a band-aid to a symptom.

Comment: Jonathan, not true.  I was not asking for a rant on how badly programmed my friends code was that you decided to give I was asking for a solution to a specific problem which you failed to offer a solution for.  You and other commenters read way too much into my question as I pointed out but you chose to ignore.  You are not in a position to preach about the program as it is written as you are unaware of the complete situation.  You should stick to answering the questions asked and not trying to be clever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and do this:

```
$test = "[u'Person 1', u'Person 2']";

preg_match_all('/u\'(.*?)\'/', $test, $matches);

var_dump($matches);

/*
array(2) { 
[0]=> array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(11) "u'Person 1'" 
    [1]=> string(11) "u'Person 2'" } 
[1]=> array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(8) "Person 1" 
    [1]=> string(8) "Person 2" 
    } 
} 
*/
```

Comment: I agree though with other comments here.  Ideally you should get it converted to JSON, or even a Python Dictionary failing that.  Python lists are flexible and thus harder to handle - can hold very arbitrary things.

Comment: What about 20 other things too.  Just responded to what was shown.    As I stated I would expect lists to be heterogeneous.  If however they are simple and consistent to what OP posted this should work.  Just trying to answer question, not wax about the 'right way'.

Comment: Hugo, who said anything about nested arrays?

Comment: ficuscr, thank-you for providing a solution to my question and not reading into it a million other things which everyone else seems to have.  This has been a very frustrating question to ask with everyone seeming to know better.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is to write a Python script that updates the mysql datastore with JSON, which can be easily parsed by just about every language out there. ( as @Hugo Dozois noted ]

Personally, I wouldn't try to read this in PHP.  The example you showed has 2 unicode strings in a flat list... but you're likely going to run into more issues and edge cases as time goes on.  You might have some unicode strings, other byte strings, some numbers... possibly even nested lists or dicts.

If you didn't inherit it, and were 100% sure of what's going on - then sure, you could parse stuff.  But it should take less than 5 minutes to write and run a Python script that converts this to JSON and solves all your problems.

Comment: Perfect solution to handle nested arrays which are very frequent!

Comment: Not in my question they aren't Hugo.  You are trying to answer a question I've not asked.